# spring boot + hibernate 5 + java 8 + ZonedDateTime = ImplicitNamingStrategy exception

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, java-8, hibernate-5.x

I have an spring boot app that leverage the java 8 and have used hibernate 4 so far. I needed however to change part of my model to include the new ZonedDateTime class provided by java8 i.e. I needed a datatime type that provide me the instance of time in utc together with the offset and the time zone. For that reason i wanted to have the native hibernate 5 support. I have replaced in my pom the the parts:

```
    //<dependency>
    //  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    //  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    //  <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    //</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and i have changed in my SpringPercisence confguration class to use the hibernate 5 instead of hibernate 4 i.e.

```
    @Bean
    public org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

//      org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.test");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }



       @Bean
//     public org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
       public org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
          HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
          txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

          return txManager;
       }

       @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }


        @Bean
        public  Properties hibernateProperties() {
          return new Properties() {


            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.chach.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");
                setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");              
//              setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

//              setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

             }
          };
       }
```

I am getting an error that is somehow related to the "sessionFactory" bean that configured above, and later it says something about ImplicitNamingStrategy. I have read here

http://in.relation.to/2015/03/31/hibernate-orm-500-beta-1-release/

that hibernate NamingStrategy has been removed but i do not understand what exactlly that mean. Since i was not able to find an example of hibernat and spring4 i hope that someone could help me out here with this one.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:935)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2575)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1908)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:707)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:649)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:392)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Addition 16 July 2015: including full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
    </parent>


    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <name>TestProject</name>


    <dependencies>          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate5Java8}</version>
        <dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<!--            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>           
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
            <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
            <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-tcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   



      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>  
      </dependency>



      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>     

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.18.1</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>



    </build>



  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

<!--         <pluginRepository> -->
<!--            <id>spring-milestones</id> -->
<!--            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> -->
<!--        </pluginRepository> -->

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
<!--        <spring-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-version> -->
<!--        <spring-version>4.2.0.RC1</spring-version> -->
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <start-class>org.TestProject.core.Application</start-class>
<!--        <springBootVersion>1.1.7.RELEASE</springBootVersion> -->
        <springBootVersion>1.2.4.RELEASE</springBootVersion> 
        <tomcat.version>8.0.5</tomcat.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hibernate5Java8>5.0.0.CR2</hibernate5Java8>
        <spring.data.redis>1.4.1.RELEASE</spring.data.redis>
        <jedis>2.6.1</jedis>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.2.CI-SNAPSHOT</spring-security.version>
    </properties>



</project>
```

Comment: Which Spring Boot version and Spring Version are you using?

Comment: @M.Deinum i am using        spring-boot-starter-parent
        1.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: @M.Deinum shell i paste the whole pom file ? It is long but i belive this is related to some configuration problem of hibernate 5 i.e. that ImplicitNamingStrategy.

Comment: No it is due to the fact that Spring Boot 1.2 uses Spring 4.1 which isn't supporting Hibernate 5, so you probably upgraded (part) of the Spring Framework in your version to 4.2 and how and which version of hibernate 5 is supported depends on the version. Neither Spring 4.2 nor hibernate 5 is production ready they aren't final releases yet.

Comment: @M.Deinum  thanks for the responce. I have just tried and upgrade the whole application to spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.3.0.M2 removed all external pom references and all version declarations it is the same problem. Basically my question is how to make use of that ZonedDateTime class thus it shows in the postgresql that it includes the time zone and the time offset. I have tired multiple thing such as "@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)" temporal annotation or using the "@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.jsr310.PersistentZonedDateTime")" but is all does not work as expected.

Comment: @M.Deinum  now the question is can i make hibernate undestand that i mean  a timestamp that shell include the offset and the time zone in UTC?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added full pom file

Comment: No you are confusing, is this error away after using the 1.3.0.M2 version or not?

Comment: @M.Deinum  this error is only happening if i  am using 1.3.0.M2. If i am using 1.2.5.RELEASE i do not have that error. This was a mistake form mi side. So this is only happening if i have 1.3.0.M2 and hibernate 5.

Comment: I still don't get it. Which error are you referencing? The startup error or the timezone stuff, it isn't clear to me anymore with all the version juggling you have been doing. I would first suggest you clean up your pom as you are basically doing everything again that is done in the starter projects... And it appears you are trying to work around spring boot in your pom.

Comment: I would also suggest not to use the M2 as after that Spring was updated (or at least tested) for hibernate5 rc2 compatibility so I suggest using a BUILD-SNAPSHOT instead or at least up the Spring version to RC3 (which was released a couple of days ago).

Answer (score 5):

Your pom is containing a lot of clutter and working around Spring Boot defaults. I suggest using the correct starters and not add the dependencies again. Also instead of using `java-version` use `java.version` this will set the correct version for Spring Boot also and thus you could remove the compiler plugin.

Also support for Hibernate 5 CR2 has been added to Spring 4.2 in the latest release candidate of Spring 4.2 (RC3). So I suggest using that instead of the one you are using now. Also I suggest specifying the `hibernate.version` as a property to trigger Spring Boot to include the correct version.

All this leads to the following pom (did a bit of cleanup and moving things around to my personal preference).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <name>TestProject</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.0-RC3</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.2.CI-SNAPSHOT</spring-security.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.0.CR2</hibernate.version>
        <start-class>org.TestProject.core.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>  
      </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wimpi</groupId>
            <artifactId>telnetd-x</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
            <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-tcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>     


    <build>
        <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.18.1</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

<!--         <pluginRepository> -->
<!--            <id>spring-milestones</id> -->
<!--            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url> -->
<!--        </pluginRepository> -->

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Note 1:** Why are you using Jetty dependencies while you are using Tomcat? 
**Note 2:** Parts of tomcat are provided others not? Why? Do you or do you not want to use an embedded tomcat.

Comment: thank you for your help. Apology for the late response. I did manage to get that up and running i.e. hibernate5 and spring boot. What is most likely very important as well as an addition to your answer is that i had to delete the <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId> in order to the hibernate5 to run, without that that did not worked correctly. The jetty dependency is just an error of mine i.e. that dependence should not be there i.e. i do want to use tomcat.